# Hi, how can i stop my 2D character to stop jumping in the air?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

He will jump always when i press the jump button. I hope you can help me guys. This is my first game so, i dont know that much. This is my code:

```
Rigidbody2D rb;
float dirX;
float jumpForce = 300f;
private bool canJump = false;
private bool hasSwitchedLayers = false;
public Transform Teleport1;
private Vector3 startPos;

void Start()
{
    startPos = new Vector3(-10, 1.5f, 0);
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();  
}

void Update()
{
    dirX = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * 10, rb.velocity.y);

    if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump") )
    {
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Force);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add an `isGrounded` boolean into your script. Add a check for `isGrounded` in your jump if statement like this `if(CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded){}`. However, you will have to add a statement to check if the player is actual on the ground. You could do this in multiple ways.

> You could use a [simple short raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) to detect if you are on the ground. `isGrounded = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, distToGround + 0.2)`, note that `distToGround = collider.bounds.extents.y`. This will create a raycast, that will travel down from the player(the distance it will travel would be from the player's collision pivot to its collision edge on the bottom plus a bit more just in case you are on a slope, etc.). It will return true if it hits any object in its path. This method would require it to be in the update method. However, you could also just add it into isGrounded itself by doing

```
bool isGrounded(){
    return Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, distToGround + 0.2);
}
void Update(){
    if(isGrounded() && .......){}
}
```

> **If your character has  a character controller**, you can also just use a simple [`if(CharacterController.isGrounded)` statement](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html)

> Another method you could use is to add a small collision sphere/box under your player's feet. This could be done in two ways. 1st, you could just have the player detect collisions, and check if that is the ground,

```cs
private bool IsGrounded;
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D c){
    if(c.tag == "ground"){
        isGrounded = true;
    }
}
void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D c){
    if(c.tag == "ground"){
        isGrounded = false;
    }
}
```

> 2nd(more complicated), you could add an empty game object in the editor with an attached collision box/sphere(with isTrigger == true) and a script. This gameobject would be a child of the player, and it should be near the players feet. In its script, you could add a static variable `public static bool isPlayerGrounded`, and then a simple `OnTriggerEnter2D` and `OnTriggerExit2D` functions, with a check if the object they are triggered by is ground by using tags.

```cs
public static bool IsPlayerGrounded;
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D c){
    if(c.tag == "ground"){
        IsPlayerGrounded = true;
    }
}
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D c){
    if(c.tag == "ground"){
        IsPlayerGrounded = false;
    }
}
```

> Then, you can check if the player is grounded in the player script

```cs
private Isgrounded;
void Update(){
    Isgrounded = NameofOtherScript.IsPlayerGrounded;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to preventing a game object from jumping mid air, but I would say that this one is the easiest. First, make sure that your game object has a collider attached to it. If it does, you would have to create a method that responds to all collisions, and you would also have to introduce a new variable called `isJumping`:

```
bool isJumping = false;
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) //this method responds to all collisions
{
    jumping = false;
}
if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump") && !jumping) //making sure that the game object is not already jumping
{
    rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Force);
    jumping = true;
}
```

While this solution may not be perfect, and you may encounter bugs such as your game object being able to jump when it collides with walls/obstacles mid air, this is the simplest solution I could think of. And, also, to try and avoid that bug make sure that the collider that you are using for this is at the bottom of your game object (so that it can jump only when it lands on the ground). Also, check out [OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) in the Unity Docs if you want to learn more about the OnCollisionEnter2D method.